# How can I troubleshoot MySQL Lock Timeout Errors with Rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, locking

All of a sudden (without any changes to related code) we are getting lock errors through active record such as:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Lock wait timeout exceeded; 
try restarting transaction: UPDATE `items` SET `state` = 'reserved', `updated_at` = '2012-09-15 17:58:21' WHERE `items`.`id` = 248220
```

and

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Lock wait timeout exceeded; 
try restarting transaction: DELETE FROM `sessions` WHERE `sessions`.`id` = 41997883
```

We aren't doing our own transactions in either of these models, so the only transactions are the built in rails ones.  There has not been a surge in traffic or request volume.

These errors appear to be when a "new" query tries to run on a locked table and has to wait, how do we see what it's waiting for?  How do we figure out which part of our code is issuing queries that lock the tables for extended periods of time?

Any ideas on where we can look or how to investigate the cause of this?

Comment: You could try going for the approach of disabling the gap lock like so: innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog=1 , it might cause some phantom records though. read about it more [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog)

Comment: What's the underlying DB engine? If its INNODB can you post 'show innodb status'?

Comment: SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS https://gist.github.com/3758910

Comment: SHOW STATUS https://gist.github.com/3758824

Comment: If you can duplicate this, or if it happens often enough, you can use mysql command client on the server MYSQL -u youruser -p and run SHOW PROCESSLIST; command, this will show you pending commands, ones that are waiting for lock etc. You can also run SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; to see more details.

Comment: We've tried show processlist and while it does show us whats waiting, it doesn't show us what it's waiting for.  It looks like the culprits are "COMMIT" - thanks mysql, very informative. How can we track down what the COMMIT is committing so we can find the problem code?

Comment: Did you recently add any new indexes to your DB?  Any other (even seemingly unrelated) changes to your Rails code base?  Any chance you can pull up an old log chunk for a similar transaction from the past and compare it to one of the failing transactions?

Comment: The problem is we can't identify which transaction is at fault.  Maybe I am missing something but it's been hard to figure out what's wrong when the SQL cited as the problem is "COMMIT".

Comment: Also look for slow SELECT queries against the tables in question - those will potentially block write, your log shows a big looking query against the items table

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at pt-deadlock-logger, while not directly related to rails, should give you a considerable amount of information about the deadlocks occurring.

http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-deadlock-logger.html

There is a nice writeup with some examples:
http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2012/09/19/logging-deadlocks-errors/

> The tool is very simple and useful. It monitors the output of SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS and log the new deadlocks to a file or to a table that we can later review. Let’s see how it works with an example.

The article goes on to explain that this can log information about the deadlock such as queries involved, which hosts, thread ids, etc.

I've also found it helpful to prefix queries with comments to allow tracking, such as the file or module, function, even which user. The query comments usually get passed down all the way to diagnostic tools like this, and could help track down which parts of code and in which circumstances are causing deadlocks.